# Cleats with asymmetrical foot positions

Tags: cleat

I am looking to buy some cleats for the first time, but due to a misplaced cast of a broken leg when I was much younger my feet do not both point directly forward, my right foot is approximately 20 degrees from forward (pointing out to the side).

Would this be an issue using cleats.

Comment: 20 degrees is a lot (more than my SPDs allow hence only a comment) but some angle adjustment is possible on many cleats. There are also products on the market to change the way cleats sit against the shoe. You may need some sort of intermediate plate as the lateral position is also important to keep your heel from hitting the crank arm

Comment: That's far enough that you're likely going to have to want to deal with a fit specialist/medical professional for your choice of clipless/clipped pedals just to make sure theres not any other major ergonomic issues (also, can you even twist out with that much foot angle?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i work with fitting, i would recommend you to look for medical advice first. Probably you need some work on your foot and then think about solutions for your foot position.